# Question regarding definition of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to be bounded if $|a_n|≤M$ for some ${M}\in \mathbb R$. Can a sequence be called bounded if it is bounded above and below by different bounds?

Comment: Yes, $c\leq a_n\leq d$ implies $|a_n|\le M$ where $M=\max\{|c|,|d|\}$.

Comment: Oh , thank you , i get it.

Comment: I should remark that the definition of ‘bounded above and below’ only works when dealing with real sequences (which perhaps is all you’re interested in for the moment). More generally, you can consider sequences of complex numbers, or even vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, or really a sequence in any normed vector space (finite or infinite-dimensional), or even more generally, a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$. In this case, boundedness of a sequence means there is a (or equivalently, for all) point $p\in X$ such that for some $M>0$ and all $n$, we have $d(a_n,p)\leq M$, i.e $\sup_n d(a_n,p)<\infty$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thats really cool, i dont understand why the notion of being bounded above and below does'nt work with sequences of complex numbers, or of such kind... would you kindly elaborate?

Comment: What does it mean to be bounded above?

Comment: It means that a number A is greater than or equal to all elements of the sequence

Comment: Does the reason have to do with the fact that some metric spaces have no total ordering??

Comment: ok. So you mentioned ‘greater than or equal to’. Can you tell me if $1+i\leq 3$? Does this even make any sense?

Comment: I see , ordering really plays a major role here

Comment: Yes, indeed. And more so than ‘have no total ordering’, it is that there is no ‘standard’ one. You can definitely cook some up, but they’re not interesting/special in any real manner.

Comment: Ah, there can be no meaningful yet special ordering on $\mathbb C$ so 1+i≤3 does'nt make sense

Comment: That was really enlightening thank you